# Hooking str.__getitem__ in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way of hooking str.__getitem__?

Example:

I'd like to be capable of do:

```
>>> "this is a string"[[1,3,4]]
'hs '
```

passing a list to [] and get the items in that list.

**A more realistic example:**

```
class STR(str):
    pass

class INT(int):
    pass
```

It's easy to make that `STR("a string")[1]` or `STR("a string")[INT(1)]` return an STR instance.

I'd like to be capable to make `"a non STR string"[INT(1)]` return an STR instance.

Comment: There are various reasons why doing this is usually a bad idea, but I think not being able to modify classes that come from C code (which includes builtins) is just an optimization.  The best you can do is either to make your INT class a subclass of int (which implies that it's immutable), or to define `__int__`, and use "string"[int(INT(1))].  (String subscripting should really call `__int__` implicitly for non-integers.)

Answer (score 3):

Why hook an often-used internal function when you can

```
def get_characters (s, l):
  return "".join(s[i] for i in l)

>>> get_characters("this is a string", [1,3,4])
"hs "
```

Comment: The above was just an example. What a really want is make a modification on the semantic of getitem without modifying the original source.

Comment: @Juanjo: Myabe you should edit your question to show what you really want to accomplish.

Comment: Done. Please see my new example.

Answer (score 2):

Methods on objects defined in C cannot be monkeypatched. The best you can do is to use an external function to complete the task.

Comment: great! so , how to do this? could you supply more details? thanks.